# incompatible types: java.sql.Statement cannot be converted to java.beans.Statement

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans, sql-update, try-catch

I am trying to make a ATM Project in Net beans but I am stack here.

```
Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
         Statement st = null;
        if (accNumField.getText().isEmpty() || pinField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please fill in the Fields");

        }else{
       
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankmanagement", "root", "");
                String query = "Select from * clients where AccNum='"+accNumField.getText()+"' and PIN="+pinField.getText()+"";
                **st = con.createStatement();
                rs= st.executeQuery(query); **                            
                if(rs.next()){
                    new MainMenu().setVisible(true);
                    this.dispose();
                }else{
                    
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Cx9.png)Can someone help me where is the problem in my code?
I am trying to get access in the database and authentication the user in my bank.
Thanks for your time

Comment: The code in your screen shot differs from the code you have embedded in your question, and the screen shot does not show the error in your title. Update your question with a screen shot containing the error message. Also: ensure that the code in your question is identical to that in the screen shot, and show the include statements for your _SignIn_ class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: incompatible types: java.sql.Statement cannot be converted to java.beans.Statement . Thats the first error in line st = con.createStatement(); .                                        
  cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method executeQuery(String)
  location: variable st of type Statement . Thats the second in line rs= st.executeQuery(query);  .